# Keycloak Auth OTP SMS SPI: How to set a non form challenge

Tags: keycloak, totp

I am using a keycloak auth Spi with sms auth which works finde for browser flow.
My requirement is to use it with direct access grant. Therefor I have to create a formless challenge which conntext the auth session between two requests.
I am struggling with passing the parameters in the response. I've analyzed the request when entering the sms otp in the login form. I know the request object in detail but I cannot figure out where to get the required parameters from the sessin object within the authenticate methid.

Params are:

- a cookie
- code
- client_id
- execution
- session_code
- tab_id

My question:
Is it even possible to use this flow without a form?
Where do I get the parameters from?

Comment: FishingIsLife did you get any solution to this problem? I am also running into the same problem

Comment: No, we used the standard flow in an eyeframe and customized the keycloak ui.